# Delete users from Profile Missing from Import view

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service, timer-jobs, delete, cleanup

I need to delete users from *user profile* in the view **Profile Missing from Import**.
 I tried to run the **My Site Cleanup Timer job** but they are still there.

How can I do?

Comment: did you run the full profile Sync?

Comment: I wish to delete them without a Full-Sync.

Comment: are these accoutns are active in AD or what are their status? and do you know why it fall under missing?

Comment: They were active in AD, now are disabled and so "not active" in SharePoint. I would like to delete them (throw interface or powershell) before the full-Synch (that runs not that often)

Comment: #Get the USer Profile Service Information
 #URL for Central Admin (where the User Profile service lives)
 $caUrl="http://central-admin:5000";
 $site= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($caUrl);
 $servercontext=[Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site);
 $userprofilemanager=new-object microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager($servercontext);
$p = $userprofilemanager.getUserProfile("domain\username");

$userprofilemanager.RemoveProfile($p)

Comment: from this link https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/b20c7de7-8181-45d5-aea4-313605fa7401/user-profile-profiles-missing-from-import

Comment: but where do I take the users? I need something to fetch the users to delete

Comment: above example you have to manually enter the user.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP... using the script provided by you,I am able to delete one user from "Profiles missing from Import".What if I want to delete 100 users of a particular domain? Can you help me with the updated script for this?

Answer (score 0):

you can delete it either manually by running the [below script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/b20c7de7-8181-45d5-aea4-313605fa7401/user-profile-profiles-missing-from-import)

```
#Get the USer Profile Service Information
 #URL for Central Admin (where the User Profile service lives)
 $caUrl="http://central-admin:5000";
 $site= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($caUrl);
 $servercontext=[Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($site);
 $userprofilemanager=new-object microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager($servercontext);
$p = $userprofilemanager.getUserProfile("domain\username");

$userprofilemanager.RemoveProfile($p)
```

OR Use the Powershell command to purge them all.

To view list of all obsolete users, run the below powershell ( give the identity of user profile)

```
$upa = Get-spserviceapplication <identity>
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -GetNonImportedObjects $true
```

To purge them run the below script.

```
Set-SPProfileServiceApplication $upa -PurgeNonImportedObjects $true
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff681014.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In some instances, where the user appears in the "Non Imported User Profiles" screen in the CA but fail to appear in PowerShell using the `-GetNonImportedObjects` switch, I found the following answer - courtesy of Bugra Postaci's blog ([https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2016/03/30/delete-inactive-users-in-user-profiles](https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2016/03/30/delete-inactive-users-in-user-profiles/))

This generates a SQL query on the User Profile Database (in which the users missing from import can be identified), and generates a command to remove them from the user profile service in SharePoint.

Solution in PowerShell:

```
#PowerShell Script – Delete Inactive User Profiles – SharePoint 2010/2013
# Credit to Bugra Postaci's blog (https://blog.bugrapostaci.com/2016/03/30/delete-inactive-users-in-user-profiles)

#The scripts is distributet "as-is." Use it on your own risk. The author give no warranties, guarantees or conditions.

if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$site = Get-SPSite "<site url>"
$ctx = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$pm = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ctx)

$ProfileDB = Get-SPDatabase | ? { $_.Type -eq "Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileDatabase"} 

$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = $ProfileDB.DatabaseConnectionString
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select NTName,RecordId from UserProfile_Full where bDeleted=1"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()

Write-host "Total Count: " $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count
Write-Host "Following Inactive Accounts will be deleted !"

foreach($user in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
   write-host "Planning to delete :" $user["NTName"] -ForegroundColor Green
   $profile = $pm.GetProfile($user["RecordId"])
    #To enable delete operation remove comment out for below line
    #$pm.RemoveProfile($profile)
    #write-host $user["NTName"] is deleted!!! -ForegroundColor Red
}
write-host "Operation Completed !"
```

Hope this helps.